# Eigenvalues of special $n \times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

Is there anyway to get eigenvalues or some sort of information about eigenvalues of below matrix? For example, $x^TAx<0$ (hence all eigenvalues are negative) whenever $b_i\leq a_i ~\forall i$.

\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & b_2 & b_3 & \cdots & b_{n-1} & b_n \\
        -a_2 & -c_2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
        -a_3 & 0 & -c_3 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
        \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
        -a_n & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -c_{n} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
Where $a_i, b_i$ and $c_i$, all are non-negative. Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: @MorganRodgers but getting $n$ degree polynomial, can we get any kind of information about eigenvalues? your introduction of $-c_1$ is good idea. appreciated!!

Comment: @RealHilbert each coefficient of the characteristic polynomial tells you *something* about the eigenvalues (e.g. the determinant and trace).  Also, when you say "the eigenvalues are negative", do you mean that the eigenvalues have a negative real part?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom   eigenvalues are negative only not negative real part

Comment: Then your supposition that $A$ will have negative eigenvalues is wrong.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom How?

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall any closed-form formula for the eigenvalues of $A$, but you may use [Gerschgorin disc theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) to help locating the eigenvalues. There are stronger versions of the theorem that give more precise locations and you may go to look them up in reference books.

By the way, the sign of $x^TAx$ is equal to the sign of $x^TSx$, where $S$ is the symmetric part of $A$. So, it doesn't matter whether $b_i-a_i$ is negative or positive, because the matrices $\pmatrix{0&\frac12(b-a)\\ \frac12(b-a)&-c}$ and $\pmatrix{0&\frac12(a-b)\\ \frac12(a-b)&-c}$ are always similar to each other. Also, if some $a_i\ne b_i$, e.g. when $a_2\ne b_2$, it is impossible that $x^TAx$ is always nonnegative, because the $2\times2$ leading principal minor of the symmetric part of $A$, i.e. $\pmatrix{0&\frac12(b_2-a_2)\\ \frac12(b_2-a_2)&-c}$, must have a positive eigenvalue.

Comment: so you are saying that if consider the case $n=2$, then matrix will have a positive eigenvalue. That is not true.

Comment: the matrix I have posted in the question.

Comment: is it a theorem? but $x^TAx<0 ~~\forall x$  whenever $b_2 \leq a_2 $. Can you give some references ?

Comment: @RealHilbert Your assertion isn't true. A simple counterexample is $(-1,1)\pmatrix{0&1\\ -4&0}\pmatrix{-1\\ 1}=3>0$. In general, $x^TAx=x^T\frac{A+A^T}2x$. So, it suffices to consider only the symmetric part $S$ of $A$. Now, if $a_2\ne b_2$, the leading principal $2\times2$ submatrix of $S$ -- say $S_2$ -- would have a negative determinant. Since the two eigenvalues of $S_2$ are real, one of them must be positive. Let $v\in\mathbb R^2$ be an eigenvector for this positive eigenvalue. Then $(v^T,0)A\pmatrix{v\\ 0}=(v^T,0)S\pmatrix{v\\ 0}=v^TS_2v>0$.

Comment: my bad I assumed $c_1>0$. but still what you claiming that should be true in the case  $c_1>0$ also??

Comment: @RealHilbert The sign of $c_i$ does not matter. $x^TAx$ is a continuous function in the diagonal. If you can obtain a counterexample $x$ when $A$ has a zero diagonal, the same counterexample still works when the diagonal entries of $A$ are nonzero but sufficiently small.